# How to lazy load a where condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lazy-loading

I'm new to LINQ

I'm trying to execute a dynamic `where` using the lazy loading, but I can't understand how to do it.

This is my code

```
protected int AnimalCount(System.Func<Animal, bool> expression = null, System.Func<Animal, bool> additionalExpression= null)
    {
    var records = (from temp in DbContext.Animal select temp);
    if (expression != null) records = records.Where(expression).AsQueryable();
    if (additionalExpression != null) records = records.Where(additionalExpression).AsQueryable();
    return records.Count();
}
```

Now, the problem is that the query is very slow, I think it's because the where clause are applied on the `SELECT * FROM Animal` list queried

Comment: It's possible that it's actually a problem with the database, such as an improper / missing index. What expression are you passing in that causes it to become slow?

Comment: Why not change your signature to `protected int AnimalCount(params System.Func<Animal, bool>[] expressions) ` ? Then you can use a loop to apply them.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but `AsQueryable()` is useless in there.

Comment: On a side note the term "lazy loading" refers to loading something on demand at the point it is needed as opposed to up front. EF supports this with properties although I prefer not to use this. This term does not apply here as you are wanting to apply a variable number of expressions to the query. I only say this so you can use the correct terminology, this is important when conveying questions / information about a subject.

Comment: @Igor thanks for the terminology correction

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You should be using `System.Linq.Expression<System.Func<Animal, bool>>` instead of `System.Func<Animal, bool>`, this is required for use with EF and I am assuming you want the expressions applied as SQL and not in memory.
- You can change the signature to use `params` and an array of expressions and then iterate over them to apply them.

Changed code:

```
protected int AnimalCount(params System.Linq.Expression<System.Func<Animal, bool>>[] expressions)
{
    var records = DbContext.Animal as IQueryable<Animal>;
    foreach (var expression in expressions)
      records = records.Where(expression);
    return records.Count();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq to entity builds the expression tree and when you request the actual data from it - it applies your request against the database and returns the result. So it's a lazy loading by default.

```
var request = DbContext.Animal.AsQeriable();

if (predicate != null) 
    request = request.Where(predicate);

return request.Count();
```

You could also go with accepting params array of your predicates as

`Foo(params Expression<Func<Animal, bool>>[] predicates)`

And then use them inside your function like this:

```
foreach(var predicate in predicates) 
      request = request.Where(predicate);
```

Comment: It doesn't work at all. EF needs to convert expressions to SQL. The OP provides *functions* though, not expressions. EF has no way of guessing what the code behind those functions is, and so has to either load everything in memory or throw. EF and EF Core 3.0 will throw. EF Core 1.0-2.x will load everything in memory, an unfortunate decision

Comment: Well, I meant Expression<Func<Animal, bool>>[] predicates and I fixed it in my answer. Sorry for misunderstanding.